# Maven install succeeds, but jar doesn't work correctly from bash (CLI)

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, maven

currently I'm working on a project in my company that imports XML data to our database. While doing this I rely on some basic configuration projects which have been already created and used in other Projects, i.e. an `EntityManagerBuilder` or other utility classes that are used in order to create a connection to our oracle database. And it seems to me that those dependencies are creating some problems for me.

My project runs perfectly fine if I start it within eclipse. And when I create the project with `mvn clean install -DskipTests` it builds all fine.
But when I want to run it from the command line the application starts and after a few lines of code just stops, without throwing any errors or exceptions.

The reason why I think that it has something to do with some dependencies is that by logging I managed to find the point where the application stops. Since it stopped at a point I could investigate, I just did that. I downloaded the sources an only added some logging and suddenly my application had no problems at all with that class, instead it just stopped with the next static call to an other class.

I have no idea at all where to search for the error. Since this is an application that has to run by it self as a monthly task, executing it from eclipse is not an option.

Hopefully someone can give me a hint how to solve this.

Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.infrastructure.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>foo-import</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>FooImport</name>

<properties>
    <company.consoleapp.main.class>com.company.infrastructure.foo.import.FooImporter</company.consoleapp.main.class>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-standalone-dm</artifactId>
            <version>${company.parent.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Logging -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Utilities -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>args4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Using foo-dataaccess -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.infrastructure.marken</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo-dataaccess</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>foo-import</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Consoleapp-Mixin -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.odavid.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>mixin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mixins>
                    <mixin>
                        <groupId>com.company.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>company-consoleapp-mixin</artifactId>
                        <version>${company.parent.version}</version>
                    </mixin>
                </mixins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be something to do with your dependency management in maven, since you haven't specified the versions and maven figures out those versions automatically.

However when you run the application, you need those jars to be in your classpath otherwise you might end up getting a ClassNotFoundException because the jars are not available. So unless you figure out what your dependencies are like you mentioned and add them to your classpath you would end up seeing the error.

It might be worth enabling a further level of logging in your application to give you some indication of where the error is. You could also try and see if at the point of failure is referenced to an external library, which is the one that is not available in your classpath.

Could you also please share how your running your application through CLI.

Comment: I think you are right about the dependency management. I'm right now looking into it and it seems that the other jar is there, but a SNAPSHOT version of it and this is somehow messing it up. I'm running it with `java -jar foo-import.jar /data -o option`. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.